# Django UpdateView: translate form labels

Tags: django, django-templates, django-i18n

I created a rather simple form using Django's `UpdateView` class, however, now that I want it's labels to be translated into other languages, I can't figure out how to do that.

Here is the code of the view class:

```
class EntityUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Entity
    template_name = "entity/settings.html"
    fields = ["enabled"]
```

And in my template, all i have is:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Save' %}" />
</form>
```

Where do I lookup translated strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should mark the label as translatable in the model itself.

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    enabled = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=_('enabled'))
```

(You could do the same by overriding the definition in the form, using the `label` argument, but doing it in the model ensures it gets translated everywhere.)

Comment: Yep, that seemed to work. However, I am not sure I want it translated everywhere. I don't quite understand all the implications of that.

Comment: I just mean in every form as well as the admin. It won't be translated in code or anywhere you don't explicitly use the verbose name.